# Angular2 - Get a specific element in the DOM and change it's class

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Let's say I have an unordered list like so

```
<div>
     <ul class="data-container">
            <li #H1>00</li>
            <li #H2>01</li>
            <li #H3>02</li>
            <li #H4>03</li>
            <li #H5>04</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What's the best way to get a element based on it's local variable using `ViewChild` then retrieving it's value and give it a special class (say class="active")

Is there a filter or find function I can use here?

Also, let's say I want to select one of the items, is there a better way than using `(click)="SelectElement()"` on all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a LiDirective to mark all LI. After that you can use all API provided my QueryList like find,filter, reduce, toArray ...

```
  @Directive({
    selector:'li'
  })
  export class LiDirective{}

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

        <div>
       <ul class="data-container">
              <li>00</li>
              <li #H2>01</li>
              <li #H3>02</li>
              <li #H4>03</li>
              <li #H5>04</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    @ViewChildren(LiDirective, {read:ElementRef}) lis: QueryList<any>;
    name:string;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
      this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      let second = this.lis.toArray()[2];
      this.renderer.setStyle(second.nativeElement, 'color', 'blue');
    }
  }
```